# C-Struct to NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I have a typdef struct such as the following:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoord[2];
} const Vertex;
```

I am creating a converter where I pass Position, Color, and TexCoord into seperate NSArray:

```
+ (void)arrayConverter: (Vertex *) v
{

    // Turn typeDef struct into seperate arrays
    NSValue *positionData = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&v->Position objCType:@encode(Vertex)];
    NSArray *positionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:positionData, nil];

    [positionData getValue:&v->Position]; // where I get error

    NSMutableDictionary *vertexdata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [vertexdata setObject:positionArray forKey:@"Position"];

    NSLog(@"\n Vertex data: %@\n",vertexdata);

}
```

The vertices I am passing in:

```
const Vertex Iso_Vertices[] = {
    {{ -X, 0.0, Z }, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{ X, 0.0, Z }, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{ -X, 0.0, -Z }, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{ X, 0.0, -Z }, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
    {{ 0.0, Z, X }, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{ 0.0, Z, -X }, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{ 0.0, -Z, X }, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
    {{ 0.0, -Z, -X }, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{ Z, X, 0.0 }, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{ -Z, X, 0.0 }, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{ Z, -X, 0.0 }, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{ -Z, -X, 0.0 }, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
};
```

What does this error mean?
Sending 'float const(*)[3] to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers

Doesn't seem as though I can get this to work how I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: why doing `&v->Position`?? just use `v`. i.e. `[positionData getValue:v];`

Comment: It means NSArray takes a _non-const_ argument whereas the data you are passing in is qualified as _const_. You can cast away the const-ness: insert a cast `(void*)`. But perhaps consider trojanfoe's answer

Comment: This is pretty basic. I suggest you read 1. a good introductory C book, 2. the documentation of the particular `NSValue` method you are using. You wouldn't have to ask this question if you had done either or preferably both of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vertex` is defined as a `const` struct. The `getValue:` method of `NSValue` expects a pointer to non-`const` memory where it can **write** its value. Of course, because `Vertex` is defined as a `const` struct, memory accessed via a dereferenced `Vertex *` pointer can **not** be written to.

The "discards qualifiers" warning (I suspect it isn't really an error unless you are compiling with the `-Wall` compiler flag turned on) specifically indicates that you are trying to pass a `const` object where a non-`const` one was expected. The `const` keyword is a **type qualifier** in C terminology.